# Graphics problems on Asus EEE 1101 HA, Precise Pangolin

Tags: 12.04, xorg, intel-graphics, asus, poulsbo

I installed Precise Pangolin x386 Desktop version via USB stick without incident.

There are two, possibly related, problems:

1. After suspend (e.g. closing the lid), the graphics are corrupted as shown in this pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BczYL.jpg. The only solution seems to be a complete reboot.
2. Upon booting, the following happens: The screen goes black. After a while the little sound notification is heard. By switching to a text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F5) and then immediately back (Ctrl+Alt+F7) I get the X session. However, the graphics are corrupted. Only the top half of the screen is used, and both halves of the desktop are rendered on top of each other. The mouse movement wrap around the top and bottom of the screen. The only solution is to log in, then log out again. After doing this the graphics are normal until next suspend or power-off.

I have tried disabling desktop effect, logging in with Unity 2D, and uninstalling Compiz, without success.

I've had this computer for years without successfully being able to run Linux on it, please help!

Comment: Suspend/Hibernation is disabled on 12.04 by default.Pls read this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop. About graphics, please run the "additional driver" from system>Preference if possible (if not, please run lspci -v in terminal and post the output for your video card here)and do install the "recommended".Please update your post after these tweaks.

Comment: Only "suspend to disk" is disabled. Normal suspend is enabled by default.

Comment: Output of lspci -v:
'00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ce
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
 Memory at f3f80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
 I/O ports at c880 [size=8]
 Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256M]
 Memory at f3f40000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
 Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: gma500
 Kernel modules: psb_gfx
'

Comment: Please remember to post your solution as an answer when the system lets you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found probably the best solution to fix graphic error: add "service lightdm restart" line to rc.local.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add to new line after coments and before "exit 0":

> service lightdm restart

Answer (score 0):

After implementing the first two options in [this post](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo#Black_screen_on_boot), issue 2 is now resolved.

Issue 1 was resolved after fixing a minor formatting error in the above link.

The command should be

```
ADD_PARAMETERS='--quirk-vbemode-restore'
```

**not** `ADD_PARAMETERS='–quirk-vbemode-restore'`